# No action was found on the controller that matches the request

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, routes

Sorry for the lame question. I've already read all similar questions and still can't resolve my issue.

I'm getting 'No action was found on the controller that matches the request' error when calling from ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/api/ToyEdit/Post/',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({toyId: 1, toy: 'asd'}),
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
    }
})
```

Controller:

```
public class ToyEditController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public EditToyViewModel Get(int? toyId)
    {
        var model = new EditToyViewModel();

        if (toyId.HasValue)
        {
            model.Toy = Data.GetToy(toyId.Value);
        }

        model.Companies = Data.GetCompanies().ToList();

        return model;
    }

    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Mvc.ActionName("Post")]
    public ActionResult Post(int? toyId, string toy)
    {
        var a = toy;
        /*new Task<int>(() => DB.Context.Toys.FirstAsync().Id);*/

        return new EmptyResult(); 
    }
}
```

Routing:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "WebApi",
            url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

What's wrong with code?

**UPDATE 1:**

OK, it works when i'm using the next code:

```
public class Toy
{
  public int? toyId {get; set;}
  public string toy {get; set;}
}

[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Mvc.ActionName("Post")]
public ActionResult Post(Toy toy)
{
    // your necessary codes
}
```

But how to pass a few primitive vars?

Comment: your maproute is not matching to the action

Comment: Web API can only bind a single primitive type from the HTTP body

Comment: But in different articles like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/795483/Do-GET-POST-PUT-DELETE-in-asp-net-MVC-with-Jquery they use multiple vars. Are they all wrong?

Comment: you are using web api and in the article, MVC is used...

Comment: @LblSS please, take a look - http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as following:
First, create `Toy` class

```
public class Toy
{
  public int? toyId {get; set;}
  public string toy {get; set;}
}
```

Then use it as following...

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Mvc.ActionName("Post")]
public ActionResult Post(Toy toy)
{
    // your necessary codes
}
```

you can take a look [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API) for more information...

Comment: Again, this doesn't explain why he's getting a 404.

Comment: Actually, in web api `route.MapRoutes` maps by url pattern... for example: "{controller}/{action}/{id}" maps an action of a controller which contains a parameter named `id`
You can take a look here - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: It seems when i'm using your code it works. But why i can't just pass two primitive vars?

Comment: @LbISS Web API can only bind a single primitive type from the HTTP body. And this is the reason of your confusion